# How to pass data from NodeJS API as a variable to a static JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, pug, mern

I have made a NodeJS REST API, which returns JSON data of questions
I have a static JS file which does DOM manipulations on client side to show different questions in an order, it takes questions from the questions array.

I am able to get data from the API on the pug render engine and to pass it on the main page, but unable to find a way to pass that data as a variable to the JS file which does DOM manipulation on the page.

I have thought of an approach to fetch data from API in the static js file itself but it doesn't seem to be an effective approach because request to API is done in the render engine itself.

My viewsConroller:

[image: viewController]

My pug template is able to access the questions:

[image: pug template and rendered page]

but I can't find a way to send questions array as a variable to the static JS file which does the DOM manipulation.

Comment: If you want the client side javascript to handle the questions and DOM manipulation, then you don't have to use the template engine for that. Instead, load the questions as a `.json` file using `fetch()` in the client.

Comment: @Kokodoko so just serve static HTML file and fetch data in static JS file which is linked in the HTML file, right?

Comment: Yes, especially if you want the questions to become interactive, it's better to execute the code in the client.

Comment: @Kokodoko thanks mate, do you think it is efficient way to do so? is there any better alternative (because the js will send fetch request during the page load)? Next thing I'll learn is react, so will that provide a better way for it?

Comment: Creating interaction on the page is always done in client code. For example, a quiz where the questions can change without reloading the whole page. If the questions never change you could use the template engine. Just don't try to create variables in the client.js file, using the template engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think fetching the json data in your static js file would be the best thing. Other than that you could do this:

```
let questions = document.querySelectorAll('.overview-box__text').map((el) => JSON.parse(el.innerText));
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working. 
Also are these two methods only way to do so?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What output are you getting?